# Reassign function variable from outside the function in python

Tags: python

I'm new to coding.
I'm trying to access a function variable from outside the function.

```
def calculate_age():
    age =10

my_age=calculate_age ()
my_age.calculate_age.age=20
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    my_age.calculate_age.age=20
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'calculate_age'
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Your function doesn't return anything, so `age` is a local variable you *can't* access outside the function. Even if you did return something, it doesn't generally make sense to try to access the function name on the thing the function returns. Maybe have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions.

Comment: Perhaps you meant: `def calculate_age(): return 10`

Comment: No. So I was trying to access the function variable from the outside by trying to change its value. Since I have assigned **calculate_age** to  **my_age** I was expecting to access the function variable age.  

def calculate_age():
    age =10
    return age

my_age=calculate_age ()
my_age.calculate_age.age=20

Answer (score 0):

I am writing an answer as I can't comment yet. Functions should have a "return" statement, which passes on the output of the function. In your case you'd need to have it like this:

```
def calculate_age():
    age =10  # ideally have a calculation here
    return age
```

Have a look on [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/) for how functions work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access that variable outside of that function. Look at this:

```
def calculate_age():
    age = 10  # this variable is local to the function. you can't access it anywhere else.
    return age


my_age = calculate_age()  # set a variable outside the function.
print(my_age)
# prints 10

my_age = 20 # change the variable
print(my_age)
# prints 20
```

This is called "scope" and you can [read about it here](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

Answer (score 0):

Like other users already mentioned, you can't do that using a function. However you can get this behavior using an object or in python called a class. extra info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

As an example, you could create a class Person.

```
class Person():
    age = 10
    height = 1.5
    lan = "Eng"

paul = Person()
```

Now you can use the instance of Person called "paul" to do.

```
paul.age #returns 10
paul.age = 20
paul.age #returns 20
```